# In a Rails update form, how do I get select drop-downs to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails form that allows users to update the values of a **payment** record they previously created.

Everything is working as anticipated, except that the select fields are not saving the appropriate value when the form is submitted.  I think this is because the helper that creates those fields isn't referencing the payment object, but I can't figure out the format I would use to do that.

Here's sample code:

```
<%= form_for @payment do |f| %>

  # Works
  <%= f.label :amount %>
  $ <%= f.text_field :amount, :size => 7 %>

  # Doesn't work
  <%= f.label :responsibility %>
  <%= select :payment, :responsibility, @resp_options, {:include_blank => true} %>

  <%= f.submit "Edit this payment" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: did you try `f.select` instead of `select`?

Comment: Please show how `@resp_options` is assigned.

Comment: @nash I did, and unfortunately when I do that I get this: http://cl.ly/3V441w2t2l1V461j0P0M

Comment: @DylanMarkow It's: `<% @resp_options = options_from_collection_for_select(User.find_all_by_group_id(current_user.group_id), 'id', 'first_name') + options_for_select({ "50/50" => -1 })%>`

Comment: @Jack7890 remove :payment from that line: `f.select :responsibility, @resp_options, {:include_blank => true}`

Comment: @nash, perfect, thanks!  Would you submit that an an answer so that I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your select statement should looks like this:

`f.select :responsibility, @resp_options, {:include_blank => true}`